# Greatest minimum distance of $9$ points in a unit square

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

> Put $9$ points in a unit square such that the distance between any $2$ points is less or equal to $1$. What is the greatest value of the minimum distance among these $9$ points?

Can it be $\dfrac{\sqrt2}3$?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  It is customary to show your work, so we have a good starting point and also can better gauge where we might help.  Can you describe your solution for $\sqrt{2}/3$?

Comment: It is a nice problem statement, but some additional context would be helpful.  Where did you find this?  Why is it important to you?  What difficulty did you encounter in approaching it?  Is there a simpler version of the problem you were able to solve?

Comment: Divide the square into 9 equally smaller squares and the diagonal of the small square is sqrt(2)/3

Comment: @kim - you divided the square into $9$ equal small squares, but where are you placing the $9$ _points_?  are you planning to put them into the $9$ small-square-centers?  in that case the min distance among them is $1/3$ only.  or maybe you are placing the points some other way?

Answer (score 1):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing for some results which may be of relevance.

**Upper bound**

If we ignore the restriction on the separation being no more then $1$ then the greatest minimum separation is $\dfrac{1}{2}$. In this case, two of the separations are as large as $\sqrt 2$ and this **suggests** that the greatest minimum separation for your problem will be significantly less than $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and therefore less than $\dfrac{\sqrt2}3$.

**Lower bound**

The convex hull of the nine points has to have diameter less than $1$. Considering the case that this region is a circle, the greatest minimum separation for your problem is $\sin\dfrac{\pi}{8}\approx 0.383$. This is obtained by putting one point in the centre with the other $8$ points equally spaced  on a circle of radius $\dfrac{1}{2}$.